# `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Tags: 20.04, compiling, gcc, make, g++

`usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libIlmImf-2_5.so.25).`
I am using [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/)
to install gcc 9.1.0 as mentioned [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) for 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
But I get errors at

```
make -j 8
```

and

```
sudo make install-strip.
```

The errors are:
`make[4]: *** [Makefile:663: sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.lo] Error 1 make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/imran_kanjoo/build/gcc-9.1.0/build2/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common' make[3]: *** [Makefile:527: install-recursive] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/imran_kanjoo/build/gcc-9.1.0/build2/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsanitizer' make[2]: *** [Makefile:643: install-strip] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/imran_kanjoo/build/gcc-9.1.0/build2/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsanitizer' make[1]: *** [Makefile:20446: install-strip-target-libsanitizer] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/imran_kanjoo/build/gcc-9.1.0/build2' make: *** [Makefile:2536: install-strip] Error 2`

however, 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' is already present. If I check using

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

I get the output similar to the questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773296/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found).

p.s. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Matlab 2018b.
I have tried many other solutions mentioned e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15).
I have also renamed libstdc++.so.6 present in Matlab path /*usr/local/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/* to avoid using Matlab libstdc++.so.6

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your problem is given by jamesloh here: https://github.com/cdr/code-server/issues/766

He wrote:

> I read somewhere that someone got the correct library from an Anaconda install.
> I confirmed by using the following instructions.
>
> ```
> wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
> sh Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh 
> cp anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 /usr/lib64
> rm /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
> ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.26 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
> ```

For me the library coming with anaconda (libstdc++.so.6.0.26) worked after copying it to the original matlab path and building the regarding link.

Comment: Didn't work for me